# How to get Mac Address from WAN IP?

Tags: c++, mac-address

I'm using `SendARP()` to get mac address form an IP.
But this function only work correctly with LAN IP.
If I have many devices in other LAN network, they will have the same WAN IP `(ex: 219.123.111.90)`, but their ports are different.

So if I call the function SendARP("219.123.111.90:80") or `SendARP("219.123.111.90:81")...,` it will return only one Mac Address.

I think the `SendARP` only get the Mac Address of the Modem without getting real devices on that LAN network.

Please show me how to get the real mac address of devices that belong to other LAN network?

Many thanks,

T&T

Comment: ARP is only meaningful within local networks, i.e. single-hop.

Comment: Thank you! but there is any way to get mac address of devices that belong to other LAN network?

Comment: In general, you don't even know that the other network is a LAN, or has MAC addresses. E.g. the other network can be a 3G network, and smartphones are identified by IMSI/IMEI.